Valibot: Password Confirmation Error Not Displaying
I'm trying to validate that two passwords match and display an error if they do not. However, the error message is not showing up in my Vue component. Here is the relevant part of my code:
const issues = ref<FlatErrors<typeof UserSchema>['nested']>();

const UserSchema = pipe(
    object({
        email: pipe(
            string(),
            nonEmpty('Email is required'),
            email('The email must be in the format name@example.com')
        ),
        password: pipe(
            string(),
            nonEmpty('Password is required'),
            minLength(6, 'Password must be at least 6 characters long')
        ),
        confirmPassword: string(),
    }),
    forward(
        partialCheck(
            [['password'], ['confirmPassword']],
            input => input.password === input.confirmPassword,
            'Passwords do not match'
        ),
        ['confirmPassword']
    )
);

// template
<template v-if="issues?.confirmPassword">
    <span
        class="register__errors"
        v-for="(issue, i) in issues.confirmPassword"
        :key="i"
        >{{ issue }}</span
    >
</template>


ensure schema validation
ensure that partialCheck function populates the issues if both  password and confirm paasword not matches
and also
make sure that this part in issues code
if (data.password !== data.confirmPassword) {
        issues.value.confirmPassword = ['Passwords do not match'];
      }

